# jquery qtip showing extra empty tip on top of expected one

Tags: jquery, qtip

I'm getting a really weird error that just suddenly started happening with my qtips:

[image]

Anyone ever see something like this?

```
$('.vote-up, .vote-down').live('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        overwrite : false,
        content : false,
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'bottomMiddle',
                tooltip: 'topMiddle'
            }
        },
        show :
        {
            ready : true,
            delay : 100,
            effect : { length : 300 }
        },
        hide : { effect : { length : 300 } },
        style: {
            padding : 10,
            textAlign : 'left',
            border : {
                width : 8
            },
            tip : {
                corner : 'topMiddle',
                size : { x : 25, y : 20 }
            },
            name : 'cream'
        }
    });
});
```

and here's the html:

```
<div class="vote-buttons" data-review="<?=$review->id?>">
    <button class="vote-up" title="This review was helpful :)">
        <span class="arrow">▼</span>
        <span class="vote-spinner">
            <b><?=$review->usefulness_positive?></b>
        </span>
    </button>
    <button class="vote-down" title="This review was useless :(">
        <span class="arrow">▲</span>
        <span class="vote-spinner">
            <b><?=$review->usefulness_negative?></b>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Share it in JSFiddle if possible.

Comment: I ended up just upgrading to qtip 2 and made some minor adjustments to the calls to resolve this.  I figured it was deprecated for a reason!  :D